# How to find Azure SDK installed on local dev machine

Tags: azure

Could someone please help me with how to find/know the Azure SDK installed on a machine?

The reason being, I am trying to use Azure Cache and it's complaining about SDK.

Answer (score 12):

I found my installs at:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK

Comment: Was easy to do before Windows 10

Comment: In my Windows 10 with VS 2017 15.7.4, it is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK`. Maybe a missing backslash?

Answer (score 4):

Should be in your `C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\<version>` folder where version  = Azure SDK version.

[image]

Comment: right, i was thinking if there's powershell or similar command

Comment: So a few things: 1) New SDK is installed in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure` folder and not the one mentioned by @Shiva above and 2) Starting with SDK version 1.8, you can have multiple versions of SDKs installed. So on my machine, I have SDK 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2 installed. BTW, which version of cache you're using?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the location has potentially changed again:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9
```

[image: Azure SDK Path]

Answer (score 0):

Users of Visual Studio can also verify installed components of SDK in Visual Studio Installer, as an alternative to manually viewing it in the file system.

**Visual Studio Installer -> Installed -> Modify** should bring you a screen with installation details. There you should be able to see installed SDKs and the list of included and not included components of your SDK.

[image: Visual Studio Installer Modify page]

Answer (score -3):

I found it in

C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\azure

Comment: Azure SDK is not installed inside python folder

Comment: And, yet, there it is. I didn't just make up a path, you know.