# Azure: Build error "CloudServices58 : Cannot load imported module named 'Caching.' " after updating Azure SDK2.9

Tags: azure

I am getting

> CloudServices58 : Cannot load imported module named 'Caching.'

build error in VS 2015 after updating azure sdk 2.9.

When I commented `<Import moduleName="Caching" />` in ServiceDefination.csdef I could build the project but a Yellow mark appears on Roles folder.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue after trying to build my Azure Cloud Service for the first time on a new PC using Visual Studio 2017.

My project used the NuGet package [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/) and as it states in the description:

> This NuGet package can only be used with the **Windows Azure SDK version**
>   **2.9** of Windows Azure Cache.

When I installed Visual Studio on my PC I had selected Azure SDK component but this installs the latest version (3.0) and this is not supported by the NuGet package.

The solution is to manually install the correct version of the Azure SDK that the project references. You can check which version your project uses by right clicking Properties in the Solution Explorer. To install the Azure SDK refer to links below.

Resources:

- [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.9](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=51657)
- [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.9.6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54289)
- [How to find Azure SDK installed on local dev machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157443/how-to-find-azure-sdk-installed-on-local-dev-machine)

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error. For this project I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and the Azure tools version of the project is 2.9.

I fixed it by going here [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.9](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=51657) and installing "MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi" and "MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi".